# A recursive solution to the number of islands

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve the problem [Number of Islands - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/)

> Given a 2d grid map of `'1'`s (land) and `'0'`s (water), count the number of islands. An island is surrounded by water and is formed by connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input:
> 11110
> 11010
> 11000
> 00000
>
> Output: 1
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input:
> 11000
> 11000
> 00100
> 00011
>
> Output: 3
> ```

An accepted solution is:

```
#Recursively solution 
class Solution:
    def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        if not grid:
            return 0
        step = 0
        r, c = len(grid), len(grid[0])
        visited = [[False for _ in range(c)] for _ in range(r)]
        for i in range(r):
            for j in range(c):
                if grid[i][j] == "1" and not visited[i][j]:
                    step += 1
                    self.dfs(grid, i, j, visited)
        return step

    def dfs(self, grid, i, j, visited):
        if i<0 or j<0 or i>=len(grid) or j>=len(grid[0]) or grid[i][j] != '1' or visited[i][j]:        
            return 
        visited[i][j] = True
        self.dfs(grid, i+1, j, visited)
        self.dfs(grid, i-1, j, visited)
        self.dfs(grid, i, j+1, visited)
        self.dfs(grid, i, j-1, visited)
```

The solution used a mixture of recursion and iteration.

How could solve the problem solely by recursion?

Comment: just out of curiousity I ask. why do want it to be recursive if iteratively it works?

Comment: Technically instead of iterating over map you can do a DFS over it, but the callstack will probably inflate too much. Idk if theres a limit to it.

Comment: cos, I am practicing recursiion @AlbinPaul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well all you need to do is change looping to recursive function that goes from some coordinate (r,c) to next coordinate (r,c+1) or (r+1,0) when end of line is reached.

Sample code:

```
def numIslands(grid, row, col):
    if not grid: return 0

    ans = 0

    if grid[row][col]==1:
        ans+=1
        dfs(grid,row,col)

    col+=1
    if col == len(grid[0]):
        col=0
        row+=1

    if row == len(grid):
        return ans

    return ans + numIslands(grid, row, col)

def dfs(grid, i, j):
    if i<0 or j<0 or i>=len(grid) or j>=len(grid[0]) or grid[i][j] != 1:        
        return 
    grid[i][j] = -1
    dfs(grid, i+1, j)
    dfs(grid, i-1, j)
    dfs(grid, i, j+1)
    dfs(grid, i, j-1)


print(numIslands([
[1,1,0,0,0],
[1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1]
],0,0))
```